# Multiply 64-bit integers using .NET Core's hardware intrinsics

Tags: c#, math, .net-core, intrinsics, .net-core-3.0

I'm writing some performance sensitive code, where multiplication of unsigned 64-bit integers (`ulong`) is a bottleneck.

.NET Core 3.0 beings access to hardware intrinsics with the `System.Runtime.Intrinsics` namespace, which is fantastic.

I'm currently using a portable implementation that returns a tuple of the high and low bits of the 128-bit result:

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
internal static unsafe (ulong Hi, ulong Lo) Multiply64(ulong x, ulong y)
{
    ulong hi;
    ulong lo;

    lo = x * y;

    ulong x0 = (uint)x;
    ulong x1 = x >> 32;

    ulong y0 = (uint)y;
    ulong y1 = y >> 32;

    ulong p11 = x1 * y1;
    ulong p01 = x0 * y1;
    ulong p10 = x1 * y0;
    ulong p00 = x0 * y0;

    // 64-bit product + two 32-bit values
    ulong middle = p10 + (p00 >> 32) + (uint)p01;

    // 64-bit product + two 32-bit values
    hi = p11 + (middle >> 32) + (p01 >> 32);

    return (hi, lo);
}
```

I want to make this faster using intrinsics. I'm clear on how to use BMI2 when available (this is ~50% faster than the portable version):

```cs
ulong lo;
ulong hi = System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86.Bmi2.X64.MultiplyNoFlags(x, y, &lo);
return (hi, lo);
```

I'm totally unclear on how to use the other intrinsics that are available; they all seem to rely on the `Vector<128>` type, and none of them seem to deal with the `ulong` type.

How can I implement multiplication of `ulong`s using SSE, AVX etc?

Comment: What about the [`Vector<ulong>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netstandard-2.1)? Using the System.Numerics.Vectors. But it seems that the ulong with multiplication doesn't give any advances.

Comment: @J.vanLangen that's kind of my question :)  None of the intrinsic multiply functions seem to work with `ulong`, e.g. `Sse2.Multiply`

Answer (score 4):

SIMD vectors aren't single wide integers.  The max element width is 64-bit.  They're for processing *multiple* elements in parallel.

**x86 doesn't have any instructions for 64x64 => 128-bit SIMD-element multiply, not even with AVX512DQ.**  (That does provide SIMD 64x64 => 64-bit multiply though, for 2, 4, or 8 elements in parallel.)

[AVX512IFMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512) (in Cascade Lake) has 52-bit [high and low-half multiply-accumulate](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPMADD52HUQ) (not a coincidence that's the significand width of `double`; SIMD integer multiply instructions use the same multiply hardware as FP).

---

So if you wanted 64x64 => 128-bit SIMD multiply, you'd have to synthesize it out of 4x 32x32 => 64-bit `vpmuludq` and some adds, including an add-width carry which you'd again have to synthesize from multiple instructions.

This would probably be slower than scalar `mul r64` for an array of multiplies  even with AVX512 available.  It only takes 4 scalar `mul` instructions to produce 512 bits of multiply results, and modern x86 CPUs fully pipeline `mul` so they can produce 1 pair of results per clock.  (Of course, store throughput is only 1 per clock until IceLake / Sunny Cove, so getting both halves of the 64-bit result stored is a problem!  But moving data to XMM registers for 128-bit stores costs more uops and also hits a 64-bit-per-clock bottleneck.)

If you only needed 64x64 => 64-bit multiply, you could drop the `high32*high32` multiply.  I wrote a C++ version of that in [Fastest way to multiply an array of int64_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296289/fastest-way-to-multiply-an-array-of-int64-t) and it *is* barely faster than scalar on Haswell with AVX2, but significantly faster on Skylake.  Either way, it would be nowhere near worth it without AVX2.

---

**And BTW, you don't need BMI2 to do scalar 64x64 => 128-bit multiplies**.

That's baseline for x86-64, with either one-operand `mul` (unsigned) or `imul` (signed).  If C# exposes an intrinsic for [BMI2 `mulx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MULX.html), it surely must expose one for plain unsigned [`mul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html) and signed [`imul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html) which are at least as efficient in most cases (and smaller code size).

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response - as you have guessed, I'm new to intrinsics :)  I do need both the high and low bits of the 64x64 128-bit result. If `mul` and `imul` are standard x86, then presumably dotnet uses those already if you multiply 2 64-bit integers (looking at a decompilation, it uses a `mul` opcode, which I guess is a 1:1 match with the x86 opcode), but in any case, .NET doesn't have a 128-bit data type (yet), so that would only get me the low bits of the result.

Comment: strange enough [there's no intrinsic for `mulx` in .NET core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86?view=netcore-3.0). So it seems the only way is to write native code calling [`_mul128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/mul128?view=vs-2019) or [`_umul128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/umul128?view=vs-2019). Or maybe edit and compile [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Runtime/Intrinsics/X86) on one's own

Comment: there are various issues related to 128-bit `mul` support: [Improve System.Decimal performance for x64 platform](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10642), [Enable long multiply](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/7065), https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/21362#discussion_r239273064, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32075#issuecomment-420467575

Comment: @phuclv: Then what's `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86.Bmi2.X64.MultiplyNoFlags` that the OP describes in the question?  BMI2 multiply NoFlags pretty uniquely describes `mulx`.  (I don't know anything about C# libraries / infrastructure or what provides what, so maybe you mean that it's not actually part of .NET Core?  There's a reason my answer doesn't contain any C# code or mention of any actual C# intrinsics, just what the instruction-sets and hardware are capable of. :P)  Or did you mean that there are no intrinsics for plain `mul` and `imul`, *only* `mulx`?

Comment: @PeterCordes my typo. I mean there's no intrinsic for `mul` or `imul` in .NET core. Only `mulx`

Comment: @phuclv: Well that's dumb.  Not all C compilers have one, but the major ones that don't have intrinsics instead support 128-bit integer types so can emit it from `a * (__int128)b`.  But there was some time when 64-bit platforms existed before a `__int128` type appeared in GCC, so I guess .NET core is at that stage of its evolution?

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the trouble comes from MSVC. Due to some unknown reasons have `_mul128` for years but not `_div128` [until the end of las year](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/315434/unable-to-perform-12864-bit-divide-on-x64.html). .NET core cannot evolve faster than MSVC itself

Comment: The intellisense docs for the .NET BMI `MultiplyNoFlags` function state `_mulx_x64`

Comment: @PeterCordes MSVC doesn't have GCC's __uint128_t type, but it does have [`_umul128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/umul128?view=vs-2019) - AFAIK this has been around for a long time, so presumably behind the scenes it can use intrinsics other than BMI2

Comment: @Cocowalla: That's correct, MSVC's C++ intrinsics for 64x64 => 128-bit multiply, `_mul128` and `_umul128` , expose the baseline x86-64 instructions `imul` and `mul`.  (If you were compiling with BMI2 enabled, MSVC could choose to use `mulx` for `_umul128`, if enabling BMI2 is even a thing).  I think you meant to say it can use *instructions* other than BMI2.  They *are* intrinsics, and aren't implemented in terms of other intrinsics.  So it's silly for Microsoft to have a `mulx` intrinsic but not `mul` and `imul` intrinsics.  Especially since `imul` is the only choice for signed multiply.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, that's what I meant, I'm just mangling the terminology somewhat :)  I just checked the ASM generated by the JIT for `int/long` and `uint/ulong` multiplication, and it does indeed compile to 'base' x86 `mul` and `imul` instructions. For `ulong` though, that will of course only get the low bits of the result.

Comment: @PeterCordes BTW, if you want to try this for yourself, I used [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io) to check the ASM generated by the JIT