# Multiplying vectors of `uint64_t` using AVX-512

Tags: x86-64, avx512

Is it possible to multiply 2 vectors of `uint64_t` using AVX-512? According to [Intel's docs](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671241), there are the following instructions which multiply vectors of integers:

- [`PMULDQ`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmuldq) (Multiply Packed Doubleword Integers) which operates on signed integers
- [`PMULHRSW`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulhrsw) (Packed Multiply High With Round and Scale) which operates on signed integers
- [`PMULHUW`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulhuw) (Multiply Packed Unsigned Integers and Store High Result) which stores the high result, not the low result
- [`PMULHW`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulhw) (Multiply Packed Signed Integers and Store High Result) which stores the high result, not the low result
- [`PMULLD`/`PMULLQ`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulld:pmullq) (Multiply Packed Integers and Store Low Result) which operates on signed integers
- [`PMULLW`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmullw) (Multiply Packed Signed Integers and Store Low Result) which operates on signed integers
- [`PMULUDQ`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmuludq) (Multiply Packed Unsigned Doubleword Integers) which only operates on doubleword values, rather than quadword values

It seems like there's no way to multiply 2 vectors of `uint64_t` in a single AVX-512 instruction (and get the low result), which seems surprising. Is it really not possible? If not, what's the rationale for this omission?

[Multiplying 64-Bit Integers using AVX2 and AVX-512 Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68706493/multiplying-64-bit-integers-using-avx2-and-avx-512-performance) is about signed integers, so it doesn't answer this question. [Fastest way to multiply an array of int64_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296289/fastest-way-to-multiply-an-array-of-int64-t) is also about signed integers, so it also doesn't answer this question.

Comment: The lower half of the result is the same for signed and unsigned multiplication.

Comment: You want `vpmullq`.  That's how compilers will auto-vectorize `uint64_t` multiplies, and you can look at the asm for a loop like `a[i] *= b[i]` to check this.  (Note that only `vpmullq` exists; there is no legacy-SSE `pmullq` since it was new in AVX-512.)

Comment: Margaret's answer on [Why is imul used for multiplying unsigned numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42587607) is I think a good explanation of another case where we use a non-widening multiply that's nominally described as "signed" (which for some reason `vpmullq` is, too, even though there's no widening form of it.)  So I made that the first duplicate in the list, along with some others that make the same point, plus an answer mentioning `vpmullq`.

Comment: Aha! I was missing that the answers are the same if you only care about the low bits. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587607/why-is-imul-used-for-multiplying-unsigned-numbers is indeed a great explanation.